# bootstrap range slider in ReactJS in jsx

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, rangeslider

I want to select a range with two sliders in bootstrap-react . i have done this but it  doesn't work.

```
render: function () {
    return (
        <input
            type="range"
            value={this.props.value}
            min={this.props.min}
            max={this.props.max}
            on Input={this .props .handle Change}
            step={this.props.step} />
    );
}
```

but i want two range sliders.what i have to do now?
i want to select values according to the slider values

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same problem when I'm developing a web application. I found some Range Sliders in **npm**. But **react-nouisliider** is my suggestion to solve your problem.

Installation

```
npm install react-nouislider --save
```

Usage

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import Nouislider from 'react-nouislider';

render: function(){
  return (
    <Nouislider
    range={{min: 0, max: 200}}
    start={[0, 100]}
    tooltips />
  );
}
```

After these steps you should include the css files in noui-slider folder otherwise you will get an ugly slider which will only have numbers.

```
import '(path_to_your_node_modules_folder)/node_modules/nouislider/src/nouislider.css';
import '(path_to_your_node_modules_folder)/node_modules/nouislider/src/nouislider.tooltips.css';
import '(path_to_your_node_modules_folder)/node_modules/nouislider/src/nouislider.pips.css';
```

You can find npm link here [noui-slider](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-nouislider)

Comment: iam using jsx files ,iam unable to use import ,as well as require is not be used.

Comment: Is there any other way than this?

Comment: you can use require also. import is es6 format of require. Don't assign it to any variable, just require it. Othrwise you can add it in src of your html page also. @Arron

Comment: jsx also supports import & require. Just require it before creating react class `React.createClass()`. Like you import or require `React` by using `import React from 'react'`

Comment: in my jsx ,it is showing require is not defined , what iam missing here,please guide me...

Comment: Are you using any building-tools like GULP or GRUNT? If yes please see questions related to require is not defined in stack overflow, if not please share your code in jsfiddle or in some other website. So that I can have a look at your code. @Arron

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114104/discussion-between-arron-and-akhil-p).

Answer (score 1):

this is my case, and it works:

```
<label>Opacity</label>
<input type="range" className="custom-range" id="customRange" 
min="0.1" max="1.0" step="0.05" 
value={this.state.opacity}
onChange={event => this.setState({ opacity: event.target.value })} >
</input>
```

of course you need a property called opacity in your state:

```
componentWillMount() {
    this.setState({
      opacity : 0.9 
    });
  }
```

i've used bootstrap 4 in my react project. bye!